# book in which man is on automated planet and programs "Squonk" to find something he needs

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember a book I read some years ago in which the main character, a man, either lands or crashes on an alien planet and is unable to explore to find something he needs. I think he may have had an injury, though it's possible that it may simply have been unsafe for him to explore on his own.

The planet is highly automated and he reprograms one of the planet's automata to find the thing he needs. He names it "Squonk," and it basically works itself to death in search of the thing. I believe Squonk does find the thing, but the man is unable to get it to let go of the search once whatever it was in found.

The time on the planet is not the main action of the storyline--my sense is that it was an interlude among multiple places visited and that this particular one was accidental.

Based on the feel of the memory, I suspect that I read it somewhere in the late 90s or possibly early 2000s, but it could have been written much earlier.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does he actually name it "squonk" or is that an approximation?

Comment: I'm remembering it as "Squonk" specifically. He'd kept it searching multiple times when it was ready to shut down/stop, to the point at which it couldn't let go of the search even when it was effectively dying. I remember that he said something like, "Good Squonk," to it several times, and there was a guilt to it. I think he may have given it something like an empty box to "find" over and over towards the end because it kept resetting itself on the search. Memory of the spelling may be off, but that's the word I'm recalling.

Comment: The protagonist and his companion in Dickson's *The Forever Man* name the alien/biological automaton they encounter "Squonk."  It is has a low-level intelligence, and is tasked by a higher-level intelligence (a Laagi) to find something and it works itself to death trying to find it.  Somewhat similar.

Comment: That's it! Thank you DavidW. That fragment has been surfacing in my head for a week now and it was bothering me that I couldn't connect it to the source.

Answer (score 8):

Having done a cursory review, I think this might be [*The Forever Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1914) (1986) by Gordon R. Dickson.

[image: paperback cover of "The Forever Man"]

The protagonist is Major Jim Wander, who is sent with a scientist, Dr. Mary Gallegher, deep into Laagi (hostile) space to investigate the surprising reappearance of a ship thought lost over a hundred years previously, and apparently still with a human pilot.

Squonk is the name Jim and Mary give to a low-intelligence alien, which may be a biological automaton, they find on the planet where they land after sent on a follow-up mission.

> Even our host member, whom we have named Squonk and who belongs to a local alien species of lesser intelligence than the Laagi, is actively unhappy unless he is constantly working during the hours he is awake.  So with the Laagi themselves.  They are born to work; and they do work until they die at their job-just as the worker bee literally works itself to death.

They have it searching for a "missing key" to give it something to do, something it will work itself to do, and Jim tries to get it to stop and rest:

> Squonk stumbled suddenly, backed up several steps and then began again searching the same area of floor he had just gone over, in the room where Mary and Jim were currently observing.  The small alien was still singlemindedly in search of the missing object that the invisible Laagi within him would recognize when he, Squonk, found it.  This was not the first time Squonk had so stumbled and backed up to search again over an area he had already examined. He had done it for the first time three days before.  Jim was concerned.  Mary had not seemed to notice.
>
> "He doesn't want to nap," said Jim.  "He wants to find that nonexistent key we've had him hunting for for months.  He's begrudging himself sleep more and more because you're begrudging yourself sleep.  He'll stop and find a place to roll over and snooze, but only when we don't seem to be in the middle of something-such as when we've just given him a new order to search somewhere he hasn't searched before.  Or when we're talking like this."
>
> "You think he can hear us?"
>
> "He can hear me," said Jim.  "At least the part of me that gives orders to him; and for all I know he can feel my emotions as much as I can feel his.  If he can to that, too, he's been picking up the backwash of the urgency I echo whenever you order a change of place or direction, or anything like that."
>
> "I don't believe he's being overworked.  That's what you're saying, isn't it,  that I'm overworking him?"
>
> "That's right.  I know you aren't doing it deliberately; but all the same you've been setting up a situation in which, to take a leaf out of your own deductions, his racial imperative to work himself to death is controlling him."
>
> "I don't believe it.  This is some plan of yours to wind up my work here, so I'll turn you loose to get back to Earth."
>
> "Sorry," said Jim.  "If you won't believe me, you won't believer me; but I think you've forgotten who controls Squonk.  Me.  He needs rest and he's going to get it.  Have you thought about what kind of situation we'd be in if he died?  I don't know how we'd go about switching to another squonk or getting back to *AndFriend*."
>
> He broke off and spoke directly to Squonk through his usual Laadi image.
>
> "Squonk, good Squonk, you can stop searching now.  Time to sleep, Squonk, then we'll right back to finding that key.  But for now, Squonk, time to rest."